# How to query Spark StreamingContext with spark sql in zeppelin?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to use spark sql to query the data coming from kafka using zeppelin for real time trend analysis but without success.

here is the simple code snippets that I am running in zeppelin

```
//Load Dependency
%dep 
    z.reset()
    z.addRepo("Spark Packages Repo").url("http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/")
    z.load("org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.1")
    z.load("org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.0.1")
    z.load("org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.0.1")
    z.load("org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.11:2.0.1"

//simple streaming 
%spark
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SQLContext}
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import _root_.kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("clickstream")
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true")
    .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts","true")


val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
  .config(conf)
  .getOrCreate()

val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))

val topicsSet = Set("timer")
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> "192.168.25.1:9091,192.168.25.1:9092,192.168.25.1:9093")

val lines = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
                                   ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet).map(_._2)

lines.window(Seconds(60)).foreachRDD{ rdd =>
    val clickDF = spark.read.json(rdd) //doesn't have to be json
    clickDF.createOrReplaceTempView("testjson1")
    //olderway
    //clickDF.registerTempTable("testjson2")
    clickDF.show

}

lines.print()
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I am able to print each kafka message but when I run simple sql `%sql select * from testjson1 // or testjson2`, I get the following error

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:343)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:646)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:281)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In the [this post](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/quickstart/tutorial.html#tutorial-with-streaming-data) Streaming Data is being queried (with twitter example). So I am thinking it should be possible with kafka streaming. So I guess, maybe, I am doing something wrong OR missing some point?

Any ideas, suggestions, recommendation is welcomed

Comment: The original uses rdd.toDf().registerTempTable(...) instead of createOrReplaceTempView(...). Have you tried the "older way"? I was also wondering - if there are several RDDs to process, the last one will be available for select only since each rdd processing result overwrites the previous ones - right?

Comment: I Tried both ways... but none's creating a temp view to query on.

Answer (score 1):

The error message does not tell that the temp view is missing. The error message tells, that the type None does not provide an element with name 'get'.

With spark the calculations based on the RDDs are performed when an action is called. So up to the point where you are creating the temporary table no calculation is performed. All the calculations are performed when you execute your query on the table. If your table would not exist you would get another error message.

Maybe the Kafka messages could be printed, but your exception tells, that the None instance does not know 'get'. So I believe that your source JSON data contains items without data and those items are represented by None and therefore cause the execption while spark performs the calculations.

I would suggest that you verify if your solution works in general, by testing if it works with a sample data that does not contain empty JSON elements.